# i18n how to use $t in translation file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, quasar-framework, vue-i18n

I'm using vuejs 3, quasar 2 and vue-i18n for my traductions.
how can i use $t or $tc in translation file like this ?
**i have the error "$tc is not defined"**

```js
export default {
  survey: {
    name: 'Questionnaire' || 'Questionnaires',
    new: 'Nouveau ' + $tc('survey.name', 1) || 'Nouveaux ' + $tc('survey.name', 2),
    wd: 'Un ' + $tc('survey.name', 1) || 'Des ' + $tc('survey.name', 2),
    mine: 'Mon ' + $tc('survey.name', 1) || 'Mes ' + $tc('survey.name', 2),
    show: 'Voir le ' + $tc('survey.name', 1) || 'Voir les ' + $tc('survey.name', 2)
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with `this` keyword ? i.e. `this.$t('survey.name', 1)` . Actually as per the error it seems this file gets called before the $tc initialized.

Comment: Thank you, but, yes i try, and this is undefined in translation file.
With your response, I think it's just impossible

Comment: In this case What you can do is - manipulate `survey` object with the translation in the file where you are actually using it instead of here.

Comment: Thank you again, but it's more effective to rewrite survey traduction, because i this translation use in many files.

Comment: I think in that case you have to manage seperate language files for each language and then invoke the particular file as per the user selected/default language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with "Linked Locale Messages" (https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/messages.html#linked-locale-messages)

So with a messages file something like this:

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      item: 'Item | Item',
      linked: 'I have got {n} @:message.item'
    }
  }
}
```

You would then do

`<div>{{ $t('message.linked', 10) }}</div>`

And the value would be passed along to the linked key.